# Not able to use thumbnail link of a google drive file in web application java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, thumbnails

I'm working with drive v2 API to upload files to google drive using Oauth2.0. This is how I get the thumbnail link of the file.

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        fileMetadata.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentFolderId)));
        fileMetadata.setTitle(file.getName());
        fileMetadata.setMimeType(type);

        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(file.getAbsolutePath());
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(type, filePath);
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f = service.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent).execute();
String thumbnailLink = f.getThumbnailLink()
```

I'm using this thumbnailLink to show images in my web application. Does this thumbnailLink  will have validity? Because when i tried to use the thumbnail link after sometime i got an 403 error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL 
/Bvz7wBXoC_pXJWfbJ44iEryxrXxB5w7JLU9He8ErJ2OjWEZg2EJCqBL1ElfIUdVx--IHqw=s220 from this server. (Client IP address: x.x.x.x)

I have tried with these *[Google Drive - Unable to download thumbnails with an authenticated (OAuth2) request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223386/google-drive-unable-to-download-thumbnails-with-an-authenticated-oauth2-requ)* , *https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/YvNs0J5IgS0*
Still I'm facing the same issue. Is there any way I can overcome this? When i upload the same image again it works for sometime but after sometime again the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[thumbnailLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) according to docs has

> A short-lived link to the file's thumbnail, if available. Typically
>   lasts on the order of hours. Only populated when the requesting app
>   can access the file's content.

So it was only working as indicated in the docs.

Comment: thank you.  Is there any way to get permanent link which can be accessed anytime for the file?